# Multiple Selection of items in GridView on Left Click

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I am trying to select multiple items in gridview on left click of mouse.
I done it with right click.
I also done single selection of item on left click like below

```
   if (this.UsingLogicalPageNavigation()) this.InvalidateVisualState();
        this.itemsViewSource.View.MoveCurrentTo(e.ClickedItem);
```

How can we do Multiple Selection of items in GridView on left click?

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to use the left button to select the items, I assume you don't want Item Click behaviour?  In that case, use the following...

```
<GridView
        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource groupedItemsViewSource}}"
        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Standard250x250ItemTemplate}"
        SelectionMode="Multiple"
        IsSwipeEnabled="false"
        IsItemClickEnabled="False" />
```

If you want to allow the item click behaviour, you would set `IsItemClickEnabled = true;` and use the built-in swipe selection mechanism for selecting items.

```
<GridView
        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource groupedItemsViewSource}}"
        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Standard250x250ItemTemplate}"
        SelectionMode="Multiple"
        IsSwipeEnabled="true"
        IsItemClickEnabled="true"
        ItemClick="ItemView_ItemClick">
```

Comment: Hi Sir, for multiple selection of items we must do this     IsItemClickEnabled="false"